# How to access the database context on the home controller

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I setup a new .net core application but it has no access to my database or _context like the rest of my controllers do. I would like to be able to access my database information on the home screen. Is this possible and if so, how can I pass a context or instantiate a database context on the home controller?

Comment: Solved by lucking into another post, for anyone looking in the future check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925122/mvc-multiple-models-in-one-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first of all modify the HomeController constructor to replace the logger with the context as follows:

```js
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly YourDbContext _context;

public HomeController(YourDbContext context)//ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
     //_logger = logger;
     _context = context;
}
```

in your methods you can use _context to access your database.